# Greasemonkey script stopped working with error: unsafeWindow.document.watch is not a function

Tags: javascript, firefox, greasemonkey

I'm very new to all of this, but this script used to work on firefox and recently stopped. It puts the unread count on Gmail's inbox to the beginning of the window/tab title.

```
unsafeWindow.document.watch('title',
function(prop, oldval, newval) {
 if (matches = newval.match(/Inbox \((\d+)\)/)) {
    names = newval.match(/\w+/)
    newval = '(' + matches[1] + ') unread - ' + names[0] + ' Inbox';
 }
 return (newval);
});
```

When this runs, the error console shows "unsafeWindow.document.watch is not a function". I tried searching on Google and here, but could not figure this out. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: unsafeWindow.document.watch is a page-specific function? from my (albeit limited) reading it is javascript and shouldn't be site or page specific. what would I look for in the page source to identify the new function?

Comment: Yes, you're right.  `watch()` isn't page specific.  It is a Firefox-only mechanism for setting a watch-points and per [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/watch) it should not be used this way.  That's no doubt part of why it broke when GM or FF changed.  I'll post a workaround in a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Greasemonkey's sandbox (XPCNativeWrapper) has changed. This seems like a possible bug, but I don't see any open issues at the moment.

Also, `watch()` is non-standard (may go away) and according to [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/watch) is [not meant to be used except for temporary debugging](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/watch#Description).

In the meantime, you can get that code working again by injecting it into the page scope, like so:

```
function AddTitleWatch () {
    document.watch ('title', function (prop, oldval, newval) {
        var matches, names;
        if (matches = newval.match (/Inbox \((\d+)\)/ ) ) {
            names   = newval.match (/\w+/)
            newval  = '(' + matches[1] + ') unread - ' + names[0] + ' Inbox';
        }
        return (newval);
    } );
}

function addJS_Node (text, s_URL, funcToRun) {
    var D                                   = document;
    var scriptNode                          = D.createElement ('script');
    scriptNode.type                         = "text/javascript";
    if (text)       scriptNode.textContent  = text;
    if (s_URL)      scriptNode.src          = s_URL;
    if (funcToRun)  scriptNode.textContent  = '(' + funcToRun.toString() + ')()';

    var targ    = D.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || D.body || D.documentElement;
    targ.appendChild (scriptNode);
}

addJS_Node (null, null, AddTitleWatch);
```

But the smarter, long-term, more robust, portable solution is to refactor the code to use an interval timer. ...

```
setInterval (RefactorTitle, 200);

function RefactorTitle () {
    var oldTitle    = RefactorTitle.oldTitle  ||  "";
    var docTitle    = document.title;

    if (docTitle != oldTitle ) {
        var matches, names;
        if (matches     = docTitle.match (/Inbox \((\d+)\)/ ) ) {
            names       = docTitle.match (/\w+/);
            docTitle    = '(' + matches[1] + ') unread - ' + names[0] + ' Inbox';
        }
        document.title          = docTitle;
        RefactorTitle.oldTitle  = docTitle;
    }
}
```